# Is it true that $\mu\left(\left\{x\in\partial K : \limsup_{r\to 0^+}\ \frac{\mu(B_r(x)\cap K^c)}{\mu(B_r(x))}>0\right\}\right)=0?$

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete separable metric space. If $x\in X$ and $r>0$, denote by $B_r(x)$ the ball centered in $x$ of radius $r$ of $(X,d)$. Suppose that $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure of $(X,d)$. Define $\operatorname{supp}(\mu):=\{x\in X : \forall r>0, \mu(B_r(x))>0\}$. Let $K\subset X$ be a compact of $(X,d)$ such that $\mu(\partial K)>0$.

> Is it true that $\left\{x\in\partial K \cap \operatorname{supp}(\mu) : \limsup_{r\to 0^+}\ \frac{\mu(B_r(x)\cap K^c)}{\mu(B_r(x))}>0\right\}$ is contained in a Borel set of $\mu$-measure zero?

I know that the result holds true if the Lebesgue's differentiation theorem holds true in $(X,d)$  (a characterization of metric spaces that have this property can be found here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.02069.pdf). However, does it hold true in general (or maybe under less stringent conditions)?

Comment: gahh, bad memory. what is outer measure associated to a given measure?

Comment: what's an example of compact $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mu(K) > 0$?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter that you don't remember what an outer measure is... it can be riformulated in an equivalent way asking "is it true that $\left\{x\in\partial K \cap \operatorname{supp}(\mu) : \limsup_{r\to 0^+}\ \frac{\mu(B_r(x)\cap K^c)}{\mu(B_r(x))}>0\right\}$ is contained in a Borel measurable set of $\mu$-measure zero?" Since it is simpler, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: can you still tell me though? also, can you answer my second comment if you don't mind? thanks!

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $X$ and $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to [0,+\infty]$ is a measure, then $\mu^*:2^X\to[0,+\infty], E\mapsto \inf_{(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A},E\subset\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n , } \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mu(A_n)$ is the outer measure associated to $\mu.$

Comment: Actually, I probably haven't got what are you asking in your second question...

Comment: oops, I meant $\mu(\partial K) > 0$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure

Comment: Well, I think that you can imitate something along these lines: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Comment: Why would the Lebesgue differentiation theorem imply the result?

Comment: $K$ is compact, so $\partial K\subset K$. If LDT holds then for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in K \cap \operatorname{supp}(\mu)$ we have that $0=\chi_{K^c}(x)=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{1}{\mu(B_r(x))}\int_{B_r(x)}\chi_{K^c}\operatorname{d}\mu = \lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{\mu(B_r(x) \cap K^c)}{\mu(B_r(x))}.$

Comment: Maybe if $K$ is the Hilbert cube in $\ell^2$ we can get some suitable product measure $\mu$ such that $0<\mu(K)<1$ as a counterexample...

Answer (score 2):

The paper "[Invalid Vitali theorems](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/701149/WSAA_07-1979-1_17.pdf)" by Preiss contain a (pretty messy) counterexample, i.e. he showed that in any separable Hilbert space we can find a finite Borel measure $\mu$ and a compact $K$ such that $\mu(K)>0$ and for all $x\in K$ we have that:
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{\mu(K\cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))} = 0.$$
Then each $x\in K$ is a boundary point of $K$ (if $x$ is an interior point of $K$, then $\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{\mu(K\cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))} = 1$), so $\mu(\partial K)=\mu(K)>0$ and for all $x\in\partial K$ we have that:
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{\mu(K^c\cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))} = 1-\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{\mu(K\cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))} = 1.$$

It seems that what prevents the existence of such pathological measures is some kind of $\sigma$-finite dimensionality property that can be used to prove a generalization of the Besicovitch covering lemma.

Comment: you should accept this answer, so that people know the question is resolved.

Comment: Yep, by the way mine is a partial answer since it provides a counterexample if the space is bad. However it may be very well the case that the space behaves bad but the actual measure we are dealing with behaves good... so my answer lacks a iff condition (an if condition is given by the answer given by p4sch)

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer: The usual proof of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem uses the *Vital covering argument* and therefore depends on the properties of the metric. In fact, one can prove Lebesgue differentiation theorem for [doubling spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space) or more general if the condition
$$\tag{1}\limsup_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu(B_{2r}(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))} <\infty$$
is satisfied for  $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$. See Sectin 3.4 (in particular Theorem 3.4.3) in "Sobolev Spaces on Metric Measure Spaces" by Heinonen, Koskela, Shanmugalingam, Tyson.

Thus, a counterexample (if one exists) should violate (1).